# Select adjacent records in Mysql

Tags: php, select, mysql

Assuming this table is ordered by date

```
id      | date      | customer
3       | 2009-10-01| Frank
1       | 2010-10-11| Bob
4       | 2010-11-01| Mitchel
2       | 2010-11-02| Jim
```

I would like to make a query so that knowing ID = 4 the resulting rows are

```
$row[0]['id'] == 1 //previous
$row[1]['id'] == 4 //most recent/current
$row[2]['id'] == 2 //next
```

A *mysql only solution* would be best, but if there is an elegant php solution that would be cool as well.

Comment: Is the table sorted by `date` column? It looks like so. Please clarify.

Comment: `Assuming this table is ordered by date` yes, by date, but if It was sorted by alphabet I assume the the solution would be similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the table IS sorted by `date` column, you can run following queries to get it:

- For previous row:

  ```
  select * from tablename where `date` < (select `date` from tablename where id=4) order by `date` desc limit 1
  ```
- For current row:

  ```
  select * from tablename where id=4
  ```
- For next row:

  ```
  select * from tablename where `date` > (select `date` from tablename where id=4) order by `date` asc limit 1
  ```

---

**Output:** These three queries return the result (one by one) as following:

```
id  date       customer
1   2010-10-11  Bob
4   2010-11-01  Mitchel
2   2010-11-02  Jim
```

Comment: This definitely works, and is probably the way to go for just three entries; if you think you might expand to e.g. 5 records before and after the result, then this would no longer work, and you would want something more generalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are ordering by date, but basing the row you want the adjacent rows on id, your going to have to do 2 queries. The first to determine the date for the ID you have selected, the second to get the adjacent rows.

Step 1 - Get the date

```
Select date
FROM   yourtable
WHERE id = 4
```

Step 2 - Get all the rows

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable
WHERE date IN (  (select MAX( date ) from yourtable where date < $datefromquery1)
                 , $datefromquery1
                 , (select MIN( date ) from yourtable where date > $datefromquery1)
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT function can take two arguments, an offset and a number of rows to return. In your case, you want the offset to be (the number of rows with dates before the desired row) - 1, or in this case 2 - 1 = 1, and the number of rows to be three. So the SQL you want is

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1,3;
```

and the number "1" will be the result of the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM customers WHERE date > "2010-11-01";
```

I don't believe MySQL will let you use a subselect or function value as the argument of LIMIT, so you'll have to store that using PHP and construct the next query that way.